# What should own the model in an MVC pattern?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, model-view-controller

Let's say that I'm drawing a solar system inside of a single `SolarSystemView` (a subclass of `UIView`). Should my `SolarSystemView` have an instance variable of class `SolarSystem` (a class containing a data structure with all of the important planetary and stelar properties), or should that be under ownership of an instance of a `SolarSystemViewController`? Or is it something completely different? I can't find any example code that gives a satisfactory answer.

I imagine that if the view owned the model, operations would be very smooth, but that also doesn't feel like good style. After all, the `SolarSystem` instance has to change dynamically somehow, and with the same or similar rate that the `SolarSystemView` updates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the MVC paradigm, the Model is supposed to be separated from the View. To get the data it needs to draw itself, it asks the Controller for it, which in turn asks the Model for it. That way, we decouple the information from the GUI. Think of it as Model Controller View if it helps. Therefore, in most cases, the Controller "owns" the Model.

For example, in cs193p, the `CalculatorViewController` (Controller) has a `CalculatorBrain` (Model) property, which it interacts with to get the results of equations to display in the View.

In your particular example, the `SolarSystemViewController` would probably have a strong reference to the `SolarSystem`, which it would poll for data that it would hand off the the `SolarSystemView` so that it could draw itself when it needed updating. The `SolarSystemView` might also notify the `SolarSystemViewController` when the user interacts with it so that it can display other views or update the `SolarSystem`, among any other tasks it could perform.

Note that the MVC paradigm in Cocoa and Cocoa Touch is a little different than the more generalized version of MVC seen elsewere, like Smalltalk. For example, if you look at the [Wikipedia page on MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) the diagram there should look different than what you've been learning. In fact, GoF (*Design Patterns*) describes MVC thusly.

> MVC consists of three kinds of objects. The Model is the application
>   object, the View is its screen presentation, and the Controller
>   defines the way the user interface reacts to user input. Before MVC,
>   user interface designs tended to lump these objects together. MVC
>   decouples them to increase flexibility and reuse. MVC decouples views
>   and models by establishing a subscribe/notify protocol between them. A
>   view must ensure that its appearance reflects the state of the model.
>   Whenever the model's data changes, the model notifies views that
>   depend on it. In response, each view gets an opportunity to update
>   itself. This approach lets you attach multiple views to a model to
>   provide different presentations. You can also create new views for a
>   model without rewriting it.

In both these cases, the Model itself is contacting the View to update it. However, on iOS, interaction between the Model and the View are handled through the Controller. This is well explained in the [first session of cs193p](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbiHXuiZM4A&playnext=1&list=PLD208B806337FCF3F&feature=results_video) as well as [Apple's own documentation on MVC relationships.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html) That way, you only need to rewrite the Controller code to reuse the Models and Views elsewhere.

Here's the MVC diagram from cs193p to clarify.

[image: Model View Controller]

Comment: That covers completely what I asked; I have one additional inquiry. What should do the "tick"-ing? There'd obviously need to be a tick for the planets to keep moving. If I understand correctly, it'd be the controller that would own a timer, at which point it would call for the model to change, then retrieving data from the model and displaying it on the screen, right? This might be content for a separate question.

Comment: @CarterPape Yes, that sounds correct to me. The Controller usually handles updates to the Model and then notifies the Views that rely on it to update. For example, a game's run loop would exist in the Controller and every frame it would notify the agents in the game (the Model) to update themselves, before notifying the View (such as a GLKView) to update itself.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, SolarSystemView should not contain any instant of the SolarSystem class.  The SolarSystemViewController should be the go between your view (SolarSystemView) and the model (SolarSystem).